# The link you followed has expired. Please try again

Tags: php, errors

I've seen some issues before when deployed Wordpress to Digitalocean droplet on the LEMP stack and sorted out by simply changing Nginx, PHP settings. However, when I try to upload a 17Mb theme it pops up this notification "The link you followed has expired. Please try again." 8Mb theme uploaded pretty well tho.

- /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini: https://www.codepile.net/pile/yQqP01xv
- /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini: https://www.codepile.net/pile/7B9dKlo2
- /var/www/my_website/wp-config.php: https://www.codepile.net/pile/XoDDGpo1

Comment: Can you SSH into your droplet and unzip the theme into the /wp-content/themes manually? That would avoid worrying about upload configuration, unless you'll regularly need to upload >10MB files. You can use curl or wget to download the theme directly onto the server, or SCP to upload a local copy to the server.

Comment: And change your database password immediately now that you shared it publicly.

Comment: @Rup thanks mate, direct uploading of the theme did help :)

Comment: @fuxia thanks for the nice catch, I too rushed yesterday to post the config file out publicly and didn't check it at before. For now, it's changed. Will be more accurate next time.